# How do Hexproof and Combat Damage interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Here's a quick question: suppose your opponent attacks with an 8/8 with Trample, and you block with a 5/5 with Defender, Indestructible, and Hexproof. You also have Hexproof.

Trample is an ability, and Hexproof won't allow you to be targeted by abilities or spells. How would one assign damage then?

Or is Hexproof just not important at all by this point?

Answer (score 8):

**They don't interact at all.**

The word "target" does not occur anywhere in the Comprehensive rules for **[702.19](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Trample#Rules), Trample,** nor **[510](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Combat_damage_step), Combat Damage Step** (well, the latter does use the word "target" within some examples, but those uses refer to spells being cast, not to the combat damage itself).

The Comprehensive rules for Hexproof are short enough to include here in their entirety:

> **702.11.** Hexproof
>
> - **702.11a** Hexproof is a static ability.
> - **702.11b** "Hexproof" on a permanent means "This permanent can't be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control."
> - **702.11c** "Hexproof" on a player means "You can't be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control."
> - **702.11d** Multiple instances of hexproof on the same permanent or player are redundant.

Because combat damage is not targeted, and **Trample** does not target the blocking creatures nor the defending player, **Hexproof** will not protect creatures or players from this damage.

Answer (score 6):

Your opponent would deal at least 5 damage to your blocking creature and up to 3 damage to you.

Hexproof prevents your opponents from targeting your creature and you in this example, but hexproof doesn't stop other things from effecting your creature or you. Things target only when they say the word 'target' on them (and Aura spells on the stack), other things like combat damage, [Wrath of God](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrath%20of%20God), [Archetype of Courage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Courage), or [Worldfire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Worldfire) do not target thus will still effect creatures, players, or anything else with Hexproof.

From the [M15 Basic Rules PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf):

> **hexproof**  —A creature with hexproof can’t be
> the target of spells or abilities your opponents
> control, including Aura spells. Your spells and
> abilities can still target it.

> **target** — If a spell uses the word “target,” you
> choose what the spell will affect when you cast
> it. The same is true for abilities you activate.

Comment: Also of note, the OP says *he* has hexproof as well. Of course, this also doesn't factor into the combat formula, but I think this is part of the question and isn't addressed in your answer.